# How can I execute query in controller in zf2

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

How can I execute query in controller in zf2. Please help me

My query like this:

```
    $fetchGeography = "select ggl.list_id
                                from gst_geography_list as ggl
                                join gst_position as gp on(ggl.list_id = gp.list_id)
                                join gst_employee_geography_relation as gegr on(gp.position_id = gegr.list_id)
                                where gegr.employee_id = '" . $id . "' ";
    //var_dump($fetchGeography);die;


    $fetchGeographyList = MainDbTable::selectProcStatic($fetchGeography);
```

Comment: is this zf2? it seems zf1

Comment: yes This is zf1 code.but i am trying to writing this code in zf2.

Comment: Ok then the answer bellow is correct :)

Comment: i use this  selectProcStatic function function is working well but some issue  $statement = $this->tableGateway->select($sql); var_dump($statement); not return any things.i am wrting code in AlbumTable.php file in ZF2.

Comment: do foreach($result as $r) on the result and then var_dump($r) inside the foreach

Answer (score 0):

In ZF2, first you need the db adapter available in the `MainDbTable` class -> `selectProcStatic` static method.

Then do this -

```
public static function selectProcStatic($sql = '') {
    $resultSet = null;

    if($sql !== '') { 
        $statement = $this->adapter->query($sql); 
        $resultSet = $statement->execute();
    }

    return $resultSet;
}
```

If you have `TableGateway` available in the class then do this -

```
public static function selectProcStatic($sql = '') {
    $resultSet = null;

    if($sql !== '') { 
        $statement = $this->tableGateway->adapter->query($sql); 
        $resultSet = $statement->execute();
    }

    return $resultSet;
}
```

In any case, the db adapter is must.